# Conditionally accumulate rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have tabulatory data as follows

```
2020-01-01 | yes | 5
2020-01-01 | no  | 3
2020-01-02 | no  | 2
2020-01-03 | yes | 7
2020-01-10 | no  | 4
2020-01-11 | yes | 9
2020-01-12 | yes | 22
```

and I want to create a new "collapsed" or "accumulated" table from this.

The output should look as follows

```
           - 2020-01-01 | 5   //5
2020-01-01 - 2020-01-03 | 12  //3+2+7
2020-01-03 - 2020-01-11 | 13  //4+9
2020-01-11 - 2020-01-12 | 22  //22
```

I basically want to add all the values of rows with `no` to the next row with `yes`. And add the timeframe between these accumulated `yes` rows as a first column.

I'm not so experienced with spreadsheet calculations. Is this possible and if yes how?

I would prefer to have a solution that works in libre office calc, but I do also have access to microsoft excel.

Comment: In Excel you could do this fairly easily with VBA, but I don't know if that would work in Libre-Office.  Is a VBA solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (using Excel):

- start with your basic data in A1:C8
  [image: raw data]
- add 4 columns: one to control when to subtotal, one for the start date, one for the end date, and one for the actual subtotal itself, using the formulas shown ((sorry, just noticed I used y/n instead of yes/no, you'll have to adjust the formulas appropriately):

[image: formula definitions]

- With a cell somewhere in the table selected, hit the "subtotal" button (in the Data ribbon, "outline" section)
- in the Subtotal dialog, set it for At Each Change in ST_Level, Use Function Max, Add Subtotal To StartDate, EndDate, Subtotal; click OK.
  [image: how to fill out the Subtotal dialog]
- collapse the resulting table to level 2 using the "grouping" controls that will appear on the left.
  [image: final result]

That gets you exactly the data you want, plus the extra "grand max" row and a few blank columns.  If you want to reduce this to exactly and only the data you want, you can then:

- select all of the relevant data cells (excluding the "Grand Max" line)
- press F5
- click "Special..."
- select "Visible cells only"
- click OK
- Ctrl-C to copy the selected cells
- paste them in a new sheet
- Format the results to your liking.
  [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer!
I followed your steps and it basically worked. Unfortunately I realized later that I need some more calculations that I couldn't fit nicely in your framework. So I spent yesterday building a python macro that calculates everything I need.

Your answer nicely solves the problem from the question though, so I'll accept you answer.